# Synonym for 'shorthand'

Tags: word-request, synonyms

I'm practicing something and I came to the word **shorthand**.
I know it's useful for fast writing and all that, but what is the other way to say that? Is there any synonym or phrase?

I need the other word or phrase for shorthand with meaning a system of fast writing, using lines and symbols to represent letters, words, and phrases

Comment: Literally, 'shorthand' is one of a couple of different systems of writing down dictation that were taught to secretaries before we had voice recorders, electric typewriters, etc.  Do you mean that, or the more metaphoric sense of 'something done to save space and time'?

Comment: I don't really understand the question.  Can you give an example of what you want to say?

Comment: @JamesK I need the other word or phrase for _shorthand_  with meaning `a system of fast writing, using lines and symbols to represent letters, words, and phrases`

Comment: Have you used a thesaurus, were the synonyms there not useful? Why can't use use the word "shorthand"?

Comment: I checked the thesaurus and the results for "shorthand" are limited and specific to something like "taking dictation", so it's unfair to close this question for not checking references, when the references are unable to provide a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on clarifying comments, a possibility is [**shortcut**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shortcut):

[Merriam-Webster]

**1** : a route more direct than the one ordinarily taken
**2** : a method or means of doing something more directly and quickly than and often not so thoroughly as by ordinary procedure • a *shortcut* to success

In this sense, *shorthand* writing is an example of a **shortcut** of regular writing.

Answer (score 0):

A synonym could be [stenography](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stenography).